# Amazon Alexa: Testing my skill, convert a text to Lambda Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have defined my intent schema and sample utterances and it works fine. I can also test it with Service Simulator and Amazon dot.

I want to write a code which gets a text and create the IntentRequest based on it (knowing the intentSchema). I can see that Service Simulator is doing something similar: it receives the text, make the IntentRequest and show it in the left box named Lambda Request.

How can do the same? receive the text and recognize the intent and slots and convert it to IntentRequest (obviously, not manually).

example: 
input: "How is the weather in Austin?"
output: a IntentRequest object similar to this:

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "....",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "... "
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {...},
    "new": true
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "reqid",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "...",
    "intent": {
      "name": "WeatherIntent",
      "slots": {...},
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me, anyway) what you are asking.  My answer to *"I want to convert a text to a Lamba request like what Service Simulator does"* would be... highlight the request content, copy it, modify it in a text editor, and you're done... (that's how I get "event" content when locally testing Lambda function code -- just copy/paste a real event from logs)... however, I have no reason to doubt that you could have figured this out on your own, if that's what you needed... which leads me to believe that I don't actually understand what you're looking to accomplish. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the question a little bit to make it more clear. of course I don't want to do that manually. I want to get a text, parse it and find the matching intent and slot values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dedicated dialog service such as Lex, API.AI, or Watson

They will get text and return the intent